# Suggestions for speeding up the query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance

I am facing issues with performance of below pasted query

```
SELECT
  leads.index AS id,
  leads.customer AS customer,
  leads.email AS email,
  leads.icp_name AS icp_name,
  DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), leads.updated_datetime) AS days_since_contacted,
  leads.contacted AS contacted,
  IFNULL(SUM(rev_sent.opens_count), 0) AS opens,
  leads.responded AS responded,
  rev_replies.category AS category,
  (blackList.domain IS NOT NULL) AS blacklisted,
  leads.first_name AS first_name,
  leads.last_name AS last_name,
  leads.title AS title,
  leads.company_name AS company_name,
  leads.company_industry AS company_industry,
  leads.company_url AS company_url,
  leads.linkedin_handle AS linkedin_handle,
  leads.geo_city AS geo_city,
  leads.geo_state AS geo_state,
  leads.geo_country AS geo_country,
  leads.custom1 as custom1,
  leads.custom2 as custom2,
  leads.custom3 as custom3
FROM
  leads
  LEFT JOIN rev_sent ON leads.customer = rev_sent.customer
  AND leads.email = rev_sent.lead_email
  LEFT JOIN rev_replies ON rev_sent.customer = rev_replies.customer
  AND (
    rev_sent.lead_email = rev_replies.lead_email
    OR rev_sent.thread_id = rev_replies.thread_id
  )
  LEFT JOIN blackList ON leads.customer = blackList.customer
  AND SUBSTRING(leads.email, LOCATE('@', leads.email) + 1) = blackList.domain
WHERE
  leads.customer = ""
  AND leads.icp_name_id = ""
  AND (
    rev_replies.lead_email IS NULL
    OR rev_replies.category IS NOT NULL
  )
GROUP BY
  leads.customer,
  leads.email;
```

here are the definitions of the tables being used

leads table:

```
CREATE TABLE
  `leads` (
    `index` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `customer` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `address` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `bio` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `category_naics_code` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `category_sic_code` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `com_sub_industry` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `company_facebook` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `company_industry` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `company_linked_handle` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `company_logo` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `company_name` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `company_sector` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `company_tech_tags` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `company_twitter` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `company_twitter_bio` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `company_twitter_followers` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `company_type` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `company_url` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `description` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `employee_range` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `employment_seniority` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `estimated_revenues` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `feedback` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `first_name` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `full_name` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `geo_country` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `geo_state` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `geo_city` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `github_handle` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `id` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `last_name` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `linkedin_handle` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `location` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `location1` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `metrics_raised` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `phone_number` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `public_company_revenues` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `qa_status` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `research_worker` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `resume_cv` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `site_phone_number` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `source` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `tags` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `timezone` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `title` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `twitter_followers` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `twitter_following` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `twitter_site` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `utcoffset` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `website` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `year_founded` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `employment_role` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `icp_name` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `icp_name_id` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `icp_name_uuid` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `icp_name_ubico_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `contacted` int DEFAULT '0',
    `thread_id` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `responded` int DEFAULT '0',
    `count_opens` int DEFAULT '0',
    `updated_datetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    `created_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `crm_owner_id` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `custom1` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `custom2` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `custom3` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `title_seniority` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    `title_function` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    PRIMARY KEY (`index`),
    KEY `customer_email` (`customer`, `email`),
    KEY `idx_customer` (`customer`),
    KEY `icp_name_ubico_id_index` (`icp_name_ubico_id`)
  ) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 1464899 DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

rev_sent table

```
CREATE TABLE `rev_sent` (
  `index` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `message_id` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `thread_id` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `subject` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `nylas_email_id` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `nylas_email` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `customer` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `icp_name` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `icp_name_uuid` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `lead_email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `opens_count` int DEFAULT '0',
  `replies_count` int DEFAULT '0',
  `updated_datetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `message_uuid` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`index`),
  KEY `customer_lead` (`customer`,`lead_email`),
  KEY `idx_rs_thread` (`thread_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=689646 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

and rev_replies table

```
CREATE TABLE `rev_replies` (
  `index` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `message_id` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `thread_id` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `nylas_email_id` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `nylas_email` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `customer` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `icp_name` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `icp_name_uuid` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `lead_email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `subject` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `body` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `category` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `reviewed` tinyint DEFAULT '0',
  `message_datetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`index`),
  KEY `customer_lead` (`customer`,`lead_email`),
  KEY `idx_rr_thread` (`thread_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=50954 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Below is the EXPLAIN result of the query
[image]

Basically the 2nd left join with OR condition causes the issue, I am not sure how can I remove that join.

Can one suggest me how can I improve join performance ?

Comment: Please update your question to show the DDL for the tables (including any indexes) and the EXPLAIN PLAN for your query

Comment: The query doesn't look vaild. You select a category and a blacklist domain, but it doesn't look like there is only one category and one blacklist domain per customer and email. Make sure you `SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';` in order to have the DBMS help you with group-by queries. Only when the query is completely valid think about performance.

Comment: @NickW added details

Comment: The query looks invalid. You group by customer  and email only and still select a lot of values that don't seem functionally dependent. In this fiddle MySQL, too, says your query is invalid: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dcdb95204152cc222b18aea1560832ce. Error message as expected: "Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'db_808640751.leads.index' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by"

Comment: @ThorstenKettner My bad! I've disabled option `sql_mode=only_full_group_by` so the query returns me result

Answer (score 1):

```
leads:  INDEX(icp_name_id, customer, email)
rev_sent:  INDEX(customer,  opens_count, lead_email, thread_id)
rev_replies:  INDEX(customer,  thread_id, lead_email, category)
blackList:  INDEX(customer,  domain)
```

When adding a composite index, DROP index(es) with the same leading columns.
That is, when you have both INDEX(a) and INDEX(a,b), toss the former.

There may be more optimizations... IF...

- Is `(leads.customer, leads.email)` UNIQUE?
- If not, then there could be a problem with the `GROUP BY` (cf `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`)
- If there is a single row for that pair in `leads`, but the other tables have multiple matching rows, then we need to turn the query inside out.

`JOINs` are performed before `GROUP BY`.  That is, `JOINs` often create a bigger intermediate table, only to have the number of rows shrunk back by the `GROUP BY`.  I am hoping to avoid this "explode-implode".

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestions. but could you please tell me what do you mean by 3rd point ? i.e `If there is a single row for that pair in leads, but the other tables have multiple matching rows, then we need to turn the query inside out.`

Comment: @deepadeshra - Add the indexes, see if they help; address the other two bullet items.  Then, if there is still an issue, I will try to rewrite the query to have a 'derived' table that contains the GROUP BY, then JOINs to the get the rest of the desired columns.